# IOS: Store and Access large datasets efficiently

Tags: ios, core-data

I have multiple JSON files which each contain about a hundred thousand quotes.

I am trying to search through all these quotes, so I need to be able to access them quickly.

It is very slow to load all these files into memory and then parse them.

What is the fastest way to store and access this kind of data on IOS? I know the SQLDatabase would be fast, but I am not adding any data once the app is running. It is all preset.
If the built in CoreData SQLDatabase is the fastest way, how can I prestore data in there? I don't want to add anything once the app is running.

Can someone please point me in the right direction, for storing all this static data in the  way which is quickest to access?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Yes, you can generate a pre-built Core Data sqlite database and package it with your project. It would be much faster than doing what you are now. There are many guides for doing it if you search for them. As it stands this question is pretty broad.

Comment: Check this post on Apple's Dev forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61745 Includes tutorials and docs